# How to a variable can manage all client request

Tags: java

I have a class, and a methodA inside.
I want to write a small program that can manager how many times methodA called, from any where, and any time.
i don't know how much to do, because i think a normal variable can do this. I think that implementation with file or database can do this but it's not so good.

Can anyone tell me the suggestion ? Thanks.

Comment: do you want to persist that when the program is down?

Comment: Certainly the program is down, the variable will be reset. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a static variable in your class that contains `methodA()`.

```
class someClass {
    public static int counter = 0;
    void methodA() {
        counter++;
        //other code
    }
 }
```

Now every time methodA is called, counter will be increased. I left it public so that you can access it from any class directly at any time to see how many times `methodA()` has been called.

Comment: is public for something special?

Comment: Public means that all classes in your project can access that variable directly (be careful, they can change it too!) Anywhere in your project, you can simply write someClass.counter to return the value of counter.

Comment: yes i know what is public, that is why i answer that... that why is public? ;) and you are wrong, in another projects too..

Comment: I thought I was replying to the question asker, my mistake. I left it public to keep it simple for duy meo. He can privatize it and setup getters and setters if he'd like.

Comment: mm getter/setter to a static field has not much sense for me! altough it's about design..

Answer (score 0):

If the methodA() may be called from multi-threads at the same time, then we may need a AtomicInteger

```
public class SomeClass {
  protected static AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0);

  public void methodA() {
    counter.incrementAndGet();
  }
}
```

[This post](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/01/how-to-write-thread-safe-code-in-java.html) introduce why "++" is not thread safe, and how to deal.